# How to add a css class to view fileds

Tags: views

i have created a view block and added some fields to it,i want to change the style of those fields with css, is there a way that i can do it.
"Thank you"

Answer (score 2):

Click on the field you want to add a css class to, select style settings, and customize field html and check create a css class. Give it a name and simply add the class to the css file of your theme

[image]

Comment: i did that but it wont work

Comment: class is not inheriting from another class.

Comment: i am using div and i also tried -Use Default-

Comment: yes i have cleared the cache .

Comment: i did not see the HTML element which i have added, and i have also unchecked add default classes.

Comment: what is i am doing wrong

Comment: I do not know where you are going wrong. If you have done everything I suggested, there is no reason why it should not work

Comment: the css class work fine with "golbal:text" field so why it's not working when i add css class to fields.

Comment: Have you inspected the views output to check if the class you have added is added or not? If class is added, then only two possibilities I can think off - The '.css' file has not been included in that page where you are displaying the result, or, the css code has been overridden at some point.If the class itself is not getting added then two possibilities I can think off are - The particular views theme has been overridden in template.php or in views tpl file, or, you have added class in one of the multiple views and accessing another. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one or two block displays of views, consider calling `template_preprocess_block()` in your `template.php` file, adding the class(es) you want to the block level, then styling the fields within the block using specificity in your CSS selectors. Example:

```
<?php
    function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
        if (your condition here to target the blocks you want) {
            $variables['classes_array'][] = 'yourClass';
        }
    }
?>
```

While it would be best to have Drupal attach the CSS classes for you, a second option would be to use jQuery's `.addClass()` method, especially if it's only one or two blocks. Example:

```
$('#myBlock').addClass('myClass');
```

Hope that helps!